# Why would github application ask write access to my private repo?

Tags: github

I'm signing up a website with my github account. But why would github allow application gain access to my private repo?

What I expect is that github should allow me to control which access I want to grant to that application.

> This application will be able to read
>   and write all public and private repository data. This includes the
>   following:
>
> - Code
> - Issues
> - Pull
> - requests
> - Wikis
> - Settings
> - Webhooks and services
> - Deploy keys

Comment: Because that's the way they made their website? How are we supposed to answer this?

Comment: Well, you can say "no"..  If you think the app in question does not need that kind of access, you should contact them and ask them to ask for less. I don't know how fine-grained the access can be, but there is definitely a "read-only" option and I think also a "read public stuff only" option.

Comment: @lanAuld indeed, just trying to understand what's the logic behind.

Comment: @user2218780 The logic behind it is "there are legitimate situations where a site that integrates with Github would need access to your private repos".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github's permissions are, unfortunately, not all that granular.

They're listed here: https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes

The site is presumably requesting the `repo` permission. It'd be nice if Github let you pick and choose which repositories to allow a third-party application access to, but it's currently all-or-nothing.

The site may or may not have a legitimate need for that permission (a CI service might need access to a private repo, for example). We can't answer that part for you - you'll have to decide for yourself if the login is worth the risk.

Comment: Currently platform such as Facebook, Github, leave this to application to decide what information do they need in order to allow user to login. At least Facebook reviews the information which application requested for. Another thought on that, it seems a breach to the private repo.

Comment: @user2218780 Github is intended for use by more technical users than Facebook's authentication flow. They've presumably judged that someone who uses Git is good enough with computers not to fall for as many scams. Yes, it's a "breach" to the private repo, but there are plenty of times you want to legitimately give access to them to a third-party. As I noted, one example is a CI service.